# how to animate image like its coming towards. For example: moving in the sky. iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, ipad, sdk

**how to animate image so that it seems like its coming towards the user. For example: moving in the sky**

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this solution

```
-(IBAction)showSignInView:(id)sender{
    signInView.hidden = NO;
    [self initialDelayEnded:Your View ];
}
-(void)initialDelayEnded:(UIView *)view {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.3, 0.3);
    view.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration/1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce1AnimationStopped:)];
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bounce1AnimationStopped:(UIView *)view {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration/2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce2AnimationStopped:)];
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bounce2AnimationStopped:(UIView *)view {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration/2];
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate image using Fade In and Fade Out -

```
- (IBAction)showHideView:(id)sender
{
// Fade out the view right away
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
    delay: 0.0
    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
    animations:^{
         imageView.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // Wait one second and then fade in the view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             delay: 1.0
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                imageView.alpha = 1.0;
             }
             completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Please see - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html